# How can I search within all subdirectories and delete all files that do not match the filetype in windows command prompt?

Tags: windows, batch-file, command-prompt, delete-file

For example,

```
Documents 
- Personal
    - abc.doc
    - 123.pdf
- Stuff
    - def.doc
    - 456.pdf
```

I want to delete all files that are not .doc under Documents directory. How can I do this with a windows batch file or in the command prompt?

Answer (score 0):

```
@echo off
    setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion

    set "folder=x:\somewhere\documents"

    for /f "delims=" %%a in ('
        dir /b /s /a-d "%folder%" ^| findstr /i /v /e /l /c:".doc"
    ') do echo del "%%a"
```

This code executes a dir command (only file paths/names `/b`, recursive `/s`, without folders in the list `/a-d`) to retrieve the list of files under the documents folder. This list is filtered with `findstr` to only get, ignoring case `/i`, the lines that do not contain `/v` at the end of the line `/e` the literal `/l` .doc `/c:".doc"`

This command is executed from a `for` command that will process each line of the output. For each line, the replaceable parameter `%%a` will hold the path/name of the file, so in the `do` clause we remove the indicated file.

`del` operations are only echoed to console. If the output is correct, remove the `echo` command

Answer (score 0):

Test this on a sample set of files.

```
@echo off
set "folder=c:\documents"
attrib +h "%folder%\*.doc" /s
del "%folder%\*.*?" /s
attrib -h "%folder%\*.doc" /s
```

Answer (score 0):

use the underappreciated `forfiles`command:

```
forfiles /s /c "cmd /c if @isdir NEQ TRUE if [@ext] NEQ [doc] del @path"
```